# Number of Islands in Binary Matrix (with wrapping)

Tags: python, matrix, modulo

I have this Python code which counts the number of islands (grouped 1's) in a binary matrix. How would I modify this to account for wrapping on the top and bottom?

```
class Solution(object):

rowLen = None
colLen = None

def numIslands(self, grid):
    """
    :type grid: List[List[str]]
    :rtype: int
    """

    self.rowLen = len(grid)

    if self.rowLen == 0:
        return 0;

    self.colLen = len(grid[0])

    count = 0;

    for row in range(self.rowLen):
        for col in range(self.colLen):
            if grid[row][col] == '1':
                count += 1
                self.search(grid, row, col)

    return count

def search(self, grid, row, col):
    if (row >= 0 and col >= 0 and row < self.rowLen and col < self.colLen and grid[row][col] == '1'):
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        self.search(grid, row - 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row + 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row, col - 1)
        self.search(grid, row, col + 1)
```

This currently returns a count of 2 but should return 1 as the bottom right island should be counted as part of the larger island after wrapping with the number on the bottom left.

```
11110
11010
11000
10001
```

Comment: You should maybe look up connected components

Comment: @ReblochonMasque connected components would mean the lower right one would be a separate island

Comment: Not necessarily; it depends on the data structure you use.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not obvious?  Your search function just needs to wrap around instead of stopping when it hits an edge.

```
def search(self, grid, row, col):
    if row < 0:
        row += self.rowLen
    elif row >= self.rowlen:
        row -= self.rowlen
    if col < 0:
        col += self.colLen
    elif col >= self.colLen:
        col -= self.colLen
    if grid[row][col] == '1':
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        self.search(grid, row - 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row + 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row, col - 1)
        self.search(grid, row, col + 1)
```

This can be expressed more simply in terms of the modulo operation:

```
def search(self, grid, row, col):
    row %= self.rowlen
    col %= self.colLen
    if grid[row][col] == '1':
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        self.search(grid, row - 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row + 1, col)
        self.search(grid, row, col - 1)
        self.search(grid, row, col + 1)
```

Comment: I think this is a great solution. Thanks for illustrating a simple and straightforward approach!